# Date() does not catch a time zone change

Tags: android, date, datetime, timezone

My application gets a response from my server with the date and time of past events. My server, however, is in another time zone and here things get a bit tricky. Server time zone is `UTC +01:00`, while mine is `UTC +03:00`. When I receive responses from the server, they come with a timestamp in `UTC +01:00`. First, I tried to receive the date as a `String`, substring it, set its time zone and then return it in a proper time format and zone. (I cut the last 4 digits of the milisec, because the `DateFormat` was invalid otherwise.)

```
private String getFormattedDate(String date) {
    DateFormat serverDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    DateFormat finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
    serverDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    String cutoutDate = date.substring(0,23);
    String cutoutZone = date.substring(27, date.length());
    String dateInProperFormat = cutoutDate + cutoutZone;
    Date finalDate = serverDateFormat.parse(dateInProperFormat);
    return finalDateFormat.format(finalDate);
}
```

This read and converted everything correctly:

> Server response: `2018-04-30T07:26:55.1524511+01:00`  ->  Substringed response: `2018-04-30T07:26:55.152+01:00`  ->  Final format: `30-04-2018 09:26:55`

However, the milisec were not always 7, so when that happened, I got an `Unparsable date` error. This made me read the date not as a `String`, but as a `Date` instead. This cut the code to only 5 lines:

```
private String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
    finalDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    return finalDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

But now, the time is always in `UTC +01:00`. I tried getting the timezone like this:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

But that didn't change anything. What exactly am I doing wrong in my second approach? I am ready to share more of my code if needed.

Comment: I always discourage the use of the old `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, `TimeZone` and `Date` classes because they are poorly designed and often troublesome. In this case even more because [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is much better suited for your particular task. I recommend you add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project so you can use `OffsetDateTime`, `ZoneId` and their friends. `java.time` is also generally so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

```
private static DateTimeFormatter finalDateTimeFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss");
private static ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul");

private static String getFormattedDate(String dateTime) {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime)
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone)
            .format(finalDateTimeFormatter);
}
```

Let’s try it out with the example server response from your question:

```
    System.out.println(getFormattedDate("2018-04-30T07:26:55.1524511+01:00"));
```

This outputs the desired:

> 30-04-2018 09:26:55

Points to note:

- The one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` accepts from 1 to 9 decimals on the seconds, so you don’t need to manipulate the string in any way before parsing.
- Don’t use your UTC offset of `UTC +03:00` as a time zone. Use a time zone like Africa/Nairobi, Europe/Moscow, Asia/Qatar or what is appropriate. It documents better why you are doing what you are doing, and it’s future-proof in case the offset is changed. Which happens more often than you may like to think.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I already tried using `jora-time`, but instead of getting the time in `String` I was receiving it as `Date`, which messed the things up even more. This is so much more elegant than my solution! Thank you so much for taking your time to explain it in more detail!

Answer (score 1):

try below code. It's a workaround solution

```
   public String getFormattedDate(String date) {
    DateFormat serverDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    DateFormat finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
    serverDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    String[] splitTime=date.split("\\+");
    String cutoutDate="";
    if (splitTime[0].length()>23)cutoutDate = date.substring(0,23);
    else cutoutDate=splitTime[0];
    String cutoutZone = "+"+splitTime[1];
    String dateInProperFormat = cutoutDate + cutoutZone;
    Date finalDate = null;
    try {
        finalDate = serverDateFormat.parse(dateInProperFormat);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalDateFormat.format(finalDate);
}
```

Comment: After trying numerous ways, this workaround was the only thing that worked properly for any returned result. Thank you!